# where is frontend user parameter in Joomla 3.8

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, front-end

I want to hide some fields from Joomla front-end Profile editor (Editor, Timezone, Front-end Language).

There was a post on this exchange in 2014 that describes the procedure: Users >> User Manager >> Options, set Frontend User Parameters to hide.

But I can't find User Manager or Frontend User Parameters in Joomla 3.8.x. Did Joomla disable this settings or move it to somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the option to hide Frontend User Parameters by accessing the User component options.

User > User Manager > click Options in the top-right corner. You will find the option you are looking for in the User Options tab. It should be the third toggle from the bottom.